# How to make sure I only print once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I am a beginner to python, I am trying to create a program that check's the password variability.

The code is finished but when I execute it, it prints the same message multiple times. But I only want it to print once.

```
def controleer_paswoord(wachtwoord):
    import re
    for item in wachtwoord:
        kleine_letter =  re.search( "[a-z]",wachtwoord)
        hoofd_letter = re.search( "[A-Z]",wachtwoord)
        cijfer = re.search ("[0-9]",wachtwoord)
        karakter = re.search ("[$#@]",wachtwoord)
        lengte = (len(wachtwoord)<6 or len(wachtwoord)>12)
        if kleine_letter == None:
            print("{0} -> Geldig paswoord?  False".format(wachtwoord))
        elif hoofd_letter == None:
            print("{0} -> Geldig paswoord?  False".format(wachtwoord))
        elif cijfer == None:
            print("{0} -> Geldig paswoord?  False".format(wachtwoord))
        elif karakter == None:
            print("{0} -> Geldig paswoord?  False".format(wachtwoord))
        elif lengte == None:
            print("{0} -> Geldig paswoord?  False".format(wachtwoord))
        else:
            print("{0} -> Geldig paswoord?  True".format(wachtwoord))

# wachtwoord = (input("Geef hier uw gewenste wachtwoord in:" ))
wachtwoord = "2w3E"
controleer_paswoord(wachtwoord)
```

---

what I get:

```
#2w3E -> Geldig paswoord?  False
#2w3E -> Geldig paswoord?  False
#2w3E -> Geldig paswoord?  False
#2w3E -> Geldig paswoord?  False
```

---

what I want:

```
#2w3E -> Geldig paswoord?  False
```

Comment: Why do you have the for loop `for item in wachtwoord`? You don't use item in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `for item in wachtwoord:` you are iterating over each character in the string, which seems to be unintended. It dosen't seem like you use `item` anywhere inside the for loop, so it just repeats the process the same way for each character. Try removing that line

Comment: @X.Feliers Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You print for *every* character in the password.  Remove that loop.  The **re** searches go through the entire password, so you don't need to loop through the characters.  The big clue is that you never use **item** within the loop -- so you are not really iterating through the string.

---

One helpful debugging hint: make your **print** statements unique, so you can tell *why* you failed on each iteration.